# Writing SQL to Trigger validation: every bill record must have at least one its detail in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I was asked to validate the Database using SQL.

The requirement is to write SQL statements to ensure every bill record has at least one detail record in another table.

Here is a summary of 3 tables associated

- Product: **ProductID**, Price,...
- Bill: **BillID**,...
- Detail **BillID**, **ProductID**, Amount

I am familiar with trigger syntax and use cases, but I don't know how to handle this. I have to solve this problem without database's structure changes.

Comment: You'll struggle to create a trigger to manage this - the issue will be that Bill Details references `BIllID` therefore the bill record must exist **before** the detail can be created, so there will be a period of time, no matter how brief where a bill record exists with no detail. You can handle this all in the same transaction and validate the transaction at the end and roll back the error, but I am not sure you'll be able to write a trigger to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I completely understand your question, but the query "to ensure every bill record has at least one detail record in another table" can be written like

```
SELECT B.BILLID
FROM BILL AS B
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM Detail AS D WHERE B.BILLID=D.BILLID
)
```

It shows bills without records in Detal-table